Where do local integrability conditions live?
Given a smooth manifold $M$ and some tensor field $A \in \Gamma(T^{p,q} M)$, we often have integrability conditions of the form $S(A) = 0$, where $S$ is some tensor field that's a function of $A$ (for example, the curvature tensor of a Riemannian metric, a Nijenhuis tensor of an almost complex structure, or the exterior derivative of a symplectic form). I struggle to understand what a natural "home" for all possible integrability tensors would be.
Intuitively, we should demand that $S: T^{p,q} M \to T^{p',q'} M$ is a "nice" function of tensor bundles, i.e. one that can be defined just in terms of the Lie algebra structure on $T_x M$ point-wise, but I don't understand how to make this intuition precise. I'm pretty sure that the answer will be either in terms of natural transformations between some cleverly defined functors, or in terms of endomorphisms of $\mathcal{O}_{M,x}$, but I can't figure it out on my own.
Is there a generally accepted definition of "natural tensorial functions" that covers most practical examples in differential geometry (and ideally one that can be generalized to arbitrary locally ringed spaces)?

There is a book about exactly this question, Natural Operations in Differential Geometry by Kolar, Michor, and Slovak: https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf.
